# Creating a 3D numpy array of from a prexisting iterable that has the appropriate shape

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have an array of M samples
and each sample has a shape of: (11, 64)
So theoretically my main array should have a shape of (M, 11, 64)
but all I get is (m,) as the shape

I tried np.array(main_array) but that doesn't do anything. 
I was wondering if there was anyway to make numpy realize the dimensionality of the data that its using.

The way I get the data is by using pandas in the following fashion:

```
main_array = data['source_info'].apply(func_to_create_2d_array_for_each_row).values
```

Comment: Are you positive that each sample has a shape of (11, 64)?

Comment: I am now positive that each sample has the same shape, but the problem still persists.  @chrisz

Comment: By any chance your method does not return (11,64) size array as string right?

Comment: @SunnysinhSolanki No it returns a Numpy array

Comment: Can you tell me what is output of print(main_array.dtype) ?

Comment: Did you try converting to list and back? `np.array(list(main_array))`

Comment: @SunnysinhSolanki dtype('O')

Comment: @PaulPanzer That works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.array` won't 'flatten' an object dtype array.  You have to use some sort of concatenate.

Make an array of arrays.  Notice that I have play some games to get around `np.array's` preference to create a 3d array:

```
In [5]: arr = np.empty((3,), dtype=object)
In [6]: arr
Out[6]: array([None, None, None], dtype=object)
In [7]: arr[:] = [np.zeros((2,3)) for _ in range(3)]
In [8]: arr
Out[8]: 
array([array([[0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.]]),
       array([[0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.]]),
       array([[0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.]])], dtype=object)
```

Another `np.array` call doesn't do anything

```
In [9]: np.array(arr)
Out[9]: 
array([array([[0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.]]),
       array([[0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.]]),
       array([[0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.]])], dtype=object)
```

`stack` treats the `arr` as a list, and joins the elements on a new axis.  `concatenate` joins them on an existing axis.

```
In [10]: np.stack(arr)
Out[10]: 
array([[[0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]],

       [[0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]],

       [[0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]]])
In [11]: np.concatenate(arr, axis=0)
Out[11]: 
array([[0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.]])
```

If one or more of elements of `arr` differed in shape, then this would not work.

`np.array((np.zeros((2,3)), np.zeros((3,2))))` creates an object array effortlessly - and possibly is a mistake.  It cannot be `stacked`.

Comment: stack worked, contactenate seems incredibly useful. Thank you!